# Check if the given value exist in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some values as below:

```
$array1 =  [
    0 => "year",
    1 => "month"
];
```

I make a loop to this array and check if its value exist in following array.

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "name" => "year"
    "mandatory" => true
    "type" => "integer"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "name" => "month"
    "mandatory" => true
    "type" => "integer"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "name" => "id"
    "mandatory" => false
    "type" => "integer"
  ]
]
```

If if exists then I have to return array something like this

```
array[
   "year" => [
        "mandatory" => true
        "type" => "integer"
   ],
  "month" => [
        "mandatory" => true
        "type" => "integer"
   ],
]
```

This is the code so far I have tried.

```
$keys = array_keys($params);
$fields = $config["fields"];

$finalArr = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {
    if(in_array($key, array_column($fields, "name"))) {
        $finalArr[$key] = array();
    }
    $finalArr[$key][] = $fields;
}
```

But this returns all the records.

Can anybody help me.

Comment: All 3 items from the first array are all in the second, so why are you expecting only 1 element? Doesn't make any sense..

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Later I can use this finalArray where I can simply check by the key " year" and "month"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over your `$fields` and check if field's name exists in `$keys`:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (in_array($field['name'], $keys)) {
        $finalArr[$field['name']] = $field;
    }
}
```